# php Sum and get average in multidimensional Array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am getting data from my database that's all working i get the right rows. But now i need to sum them and calculate the average.

My current code is:

```
$new = array();
                foreach($testquery as $key){
                    $new[$key['school']][$key['city_id']][] = array('points'=>$key['points']);
                }
```

My array structure is like this:

```
    [Etelä-Tapiolan lukio] => Array
            (
                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [points] => 5
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [points] => 5
                            )

                    )

            )


    [Oulunsalo lukio] => Array
            (
                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [points] => 4
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [points] => 6
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [points] => 6
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [points] => 7
                            )

                    )

            )

  [Limingan lukio] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 5
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 3
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 3
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 4
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 6
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 4
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 6
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 3
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 3
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 5
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [points] => 7
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

There is no limit on array sizes. Now i need to sum up the points and then divide the sum with the number of points each array has.

The output should be:

- Etelä-Tapiolan lukio: 5 (Explanation 5+5 = 10/2 = 5)
- Oulunsalo lukio: 5,75 (Explanation 4+6+6+7 = 23/4 = 5,75)
- Limingan lukio: 4.41 (Explanation 4+5+3+3+4+6+4+6+3+3+5+7 = 53/12 = 4.41)

I also need the ID = [4],[8],[2] number

```
[Etelä-Tapiolan lukio] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
[Oulunsalo lukio] => Array
                (
                    [8] => Array
[Limingan lukio] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
```

The final output is going to be:

```
<td class="4">Etelä-Tapiolan lukio:><span> 5 </span></td>
<td class="8">Oulunsalo lukio:><span> 5,75 </span></td>
<td class="2">Limingan lukio:><span> 4.41 </span></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you could just use a foreach in this case. Example:

```
$total = array();
foreach ($new as $name_key => $stats) {
    foreach($stats as $class => $info) {
        $count = count($info); // get the count of individual points

        $sum = array_sum(array_map(function($piece){ // then, sum them
            return $piece['points']; // return each points
        }, $info));

        $total[$name_key][$class] = sprintf('%1.2f', $sum / $count); // normal average
    }
}

?>
<!-- present it on a table -->
<table>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($total as $name => $value): ?>
        <?php foreach ($value as $class => $ave): ?>
            <td class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?><span><?php echo $ave; ?></span></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hL9KeN)